# Compositor: How to crop an image into multiple versions?

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, scale

For cases where we want to batch process an image into multiple versions, it's fairly straightforward if only changing the scale. But if we want to vary the cropping things get complicated. This is because using the Scale node's Crop mode on either *Render Size* or *Scene Size*. Neither of these values can have multiple instances or be key-framed to change over time.

[image: Trying to figure out how to crop and resize to more than one version]

In the screen shot above, the resizing (cropping) only works correctly because the Render Size is set correctly.

[image]

But this can only be done once. Even if we create another scene with different render dimensions, only the current scene gets used by the Scale node.

Using the Scale node in *Absolute* mode causes stretching instead of cropping.

It seems like there should be a way to do this. Am I overlooking something?

**Update:** I've made some progress with the size by using a Translate node followed by a Crop node, but the crop is off-center.

[image: Cropping to the correct size, but is not centered]

Comment: It could possibly be done with Python. Could you tell more about the batch process you need?

Comment: @MartinZ Your comment made me realize I'm probably using the wrong software. I think I should be using imagemagick for this, not Blender. Still, it's frustrating to think that maybe Blender can't do it... Blender can do ANYTHING! ;-)

Comment: @MartinZ [The batch process I need](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18545)

Comment: @Mentalist You can use python in blender for batchrendering and everything you do by hand (except for knowledge only you as a human have and can't possibly share)

Comment: If you tell me the workflow as good as you can I can help you write the script

Comment: @WhatAMesh Thank you. Basically I will have a hi-res master image that will need to be resized to various different smaller sizes. These smaller sizes have aspect ratios different from the original, so the only way to prevent stretching is to crop the smaller dimension.

Comment: @WhatAMesh Before you go digging into Python code to help me, I should let you know I've found an app called [XnConvert](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/) that does exactly what I need. It would've been fun to do it in Blender (tried imagemagick too, but its documentation quickly frustrated me)... however I found another solution. Since others may want to do this in Blender, I think the question is still valid and worth answering. But I'm not going to lose any more sleep over these nodes. Thanks for being helpful!

Comment: @WhatAMesh Sorry, I jumped to conclusions. XnConvert is good, but after further tests I've discovered it doesn't keep the image centered when scaled and cropped. Maybe I will need to use Blender after all to get precise control.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the images after you cropped them? Just save them? It sounds to me like you just have an image and want to crop it at different parts to get different image ratios

Comment: It's possible in Blender, but it will be easier to do with Imagemagick.

Comment: @MartinZ I tried using imagemagick, looking at examples of scripts others have made and piecing together something custom of my own, but my syntax is wrong somewhere and I don't know where. In the end, using Photoshop Actions (Image Size & Canvas Size) turned out to be the most effective solution. I realized that outputting images of multiple sizes in Blender is impossible because after scaling down a transparent border remains since Blender's image will always be the dimensions of the main scene.

Comment: @MartinZ Update: While doing this in Ps was *working*, some aspects of the Actions flow was annoying me, so I decided to give imagemagick another try. I [got some help over at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765357/imagemagick-how-to-scale-and-crop-a-folder-of-images) and now have a script that does exactly what I want  - instantaneously. :-)

Comment: This is usefull. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in Blender, because the image pixel dimensions will always be that of the Scene from which the Render button was pushed.

I used a File Output node to test this, saving rendered data from different Scenes, each with different render dimensions. Their dimensions were overridden by the dimensions of the main Scene.

I'll post the .blend for anyone curious. It's nothing special.

[image]

What this means is that even if you use nodes to get the scaling and cropping right, you will just end up with transparency around the image. (If scaling *up* your image will be clipped instead.)

This sort of task should be done with other software, such as imagemagick or Photoshop (using Actions). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51771824/2454914) is how to do it with imagemagick using scripting.

Comment: You have Python in Blender. There is no such a thing as 'can't be done'. You can batch process a folder with images in Blender with a script changing the dimensions and rerendering the compositor nodes only with Render Layer nodes muted. It is not as elegant or practical as with ImageMagick though.